# How do I help my party achieve their dreams?

Tags: dangerous-adventure

I noticed there is an area called "Dreams", with a book that lists various dreams my party wants to eventually see come to pass.

Problem is, I can't really figure out to achieve them.

How do I help my party achieve their dreams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dreams are not a form of achievement or unlockable.  Instead, they are purchasable bonuses, with one dream available for each character.  Each dream costs a set amount of gold, which may differ for each dream, and provides one specific bonus.  Dreams may only be purchased once.  Once purchased, that benefit is then applied to your game.

Basically, you may need to click on a dream to see how much it costs (say, 2 thousand gold).  Once you have the funds (repeated play-throughs of easier dungeons, use of the yellow thief's special ability, looting the one-time chests), you can purchase the dream.  You get to see the full image, and then the bonus is applied.

Note that doing all five dreams will not complete the game.  You still have the rest of the dungeons to play through.  It will, however, make things easier, such as giving you an extra move (highly recommended), extra health, etc.